# What the name of this icons if it exists in FontAwesome ..?

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I haven't found this Icon's name in font awesome does anyone know it's name ??

[image]

I tried to search with Google Image but nothing ...

[image: Google image Results]

Thanks

Comment: are you sure it's a font awesome icon? i found this only https://fontawesome.com/icons/map-signs?style=solid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a font-awesome icon, the closest you have it's the map-signs one:

[image: map-signs]

Check the cheatsheet at https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet for all the icons.

Comment: Thanks Eudald, i thought  it exists in FontAwesome I will vectorise it and use it as svg